# Canceling the activity in the application not working-Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have recorded the below scenario and recorded the script from blaze meter, Canceling NLI is recorded but while running the script NLI canceling not working due to that particular sampler is failing

Logged into an app
navigated to the "XXXX" Tab and hit "XXXX" page
Searched records by giving From date and to date
hit Search button
presented with 1 record with unique ATI number
submitted NLI
Canceled NLI (because next user need to NLI the same  ATI number)
logged out from application

please advise on how to cancel particular activity to pass the sampler, is there any code we need to write in jmeter? please help me

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 options:

1. "Action to be taken after a Sampler error" setting on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level:

   [image]

   where you have the choice to start next loop, stop the thread or stop the test
2. Using the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/), given the below configuration:

   [image]

   `Sampler B` will only be executed if `Sampler A` is successful

Comment: This solution wont work for me, because i don't required to stop the test or if controller, I wanted to make the cancel functionality should work, here script not canceling the NLI functionality in the application.  Response Data showing as this {"status":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"criteria parameter is missing"}